# How to convert List of JSON frames to JSON frame

Tags: python, json, list, python-2.7

I want to convert List of JSON object ot Single JSON frame

Here is my code

```
for i in user1:
    name=i.name
    password=i.password
    id1=i.id
    user = { "name" : name,
              "password" : password,
              "id":id1}
    user = json.dumps(user)
    userid.append(user)
```

I am getting output is

> ['{"password": "A123", "name": "Sam", "id": 1}', '{"password":
>   "B123", "name": "Sammy", "id": 2}', '{"password": "C123", "name":
>   "Abhi", "id": 3}']

What I want is something like

> {{"password": "A123", "name": "Sam", "id": 1},{"password":
>   "B123", "name": "Sammy", "id": 2},{"password": "C123", "name":
>   "Abhi", "id": 3}}

Comment: Your sample output is not valid JSON. You can have a list with `[]` or an objects with keys.

Comment: Yes @KlausD. but I want to make nested JSON frames. Can this be possible?

Comment: In the new JSON there is ambiguity with more than one key "password" - you cannot do that as your example indicate. What you can do is to give an unique key for each inner JSON.

Comment: userid.append(user) is to add in List object is there anything which adds in JSON or something?

Comment: Thanks . I'll try and let you know @GalDreiman

Comment: Do you want your output to be a JSON or do you actually want a python dict instead? JSON is a format. If you want your output to be a JSON, it will most likely be represented in a string.

Comment: @AbhishekParikh If you really want a Nested JSON, create a unique key such as, a combination of password and name. In this case, the new `key` of the JSON will be the unique key & the sub JSON document will be its `value`.

Comment: Okay So finally what I've done is made ID as primary key and made nested JSON frame as ID is unique. Is this method true?

Comment: {1: {'password': u'OSPL', 'name': u'Sandeep'}, 2: {'password': u'FORD', 'name': u'Ford'}, 3: {'password': u'OSPL123', 'name': u'Abhishek'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.dumps()` returns a string, so you're append strings to `userid`—and thus end up with the list of strings shown.

If you want a dictionary of dictionaries using the `id` as the primary key, all you need is:

```
users = {i.id: {"name": i.name, "password": i.password} for i in user1}
```

Comment: Thanks @martineau but what I want is dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: @Abhishek: Oh...that wasn't clear from your question. Given that information, I've updated my answer which assumes you want use the user's `id` as the key for values in the outer dictionary (since it will need to be something unique for each entry in it).

Answer (score 0):

What I've done now is

```
user = {}
name,password,id1 = [],[],[]
user1=session.query(User).all()
for i in user1:
    name=i.name
    password=i.password
    id1=i.id
    user.update({ id1:{
            "name" : name,
            "password" : password,
          }
        })
```

Thanks all for your support