# Python: add to a dictionary in a list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary (It is for creating json),

```
temp = {'logs':[]}
```

I want to append dictionaries, but i only got 1 key:val at a time.

what I tried:

```
temp['logs'].append({key:val})
```

This does as expected and appends the dict to the array.
But now I want to add a key/val pair to this dictionary, how can I do this? 
I've tried using append/extend but that just adds a new dictionary to the list.

Comment: I have tried looking on stack overflow already. please don't downvote my question. If you can find a question like this already asked, I'd really appreciate it. Asking a new question, means its my last resort.

Comment: Can you share an example of the output you'd like to get? I fear I'm not following the question properly.

Comment: try `temp['logs'].append((key,val))`

Comment: I am trying to create a dict, for a future JSON.dumps(). I am getting the key/value from a generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But now I want to add a key/val pair to this dictionary

You can *index* the list and *update* that dictionary:

```
temp['logs'][0].update({'new_key': 'new_value'})
```

Comment: That might actually be what I'm looking for thank you! I'll give it a shot!

Comment: The *downvoter* can please leave a comment in case I missed something

Comment: seems to answer to the question imo

Comment: Is there any way to do this so I don't have to do the 
    ...['logs'][0]...  
I would like to avoid having to reference the point in the list, as at a point, I'll need to append a new dictionary and repeat. There's probably a fun function I can create to do it if I must.

Comment: @Islarf You need to at least know the index of the dictionary you want to update. `[0]` does it. You can use `['logs'][-1]` which takes the last item in the list without having to know its index

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thank you very much, totally forgot about the [-1]. always forget that lists in python can do that, this should work thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to change your dict values :

```
>>> temp['logs'][0]={'no':'val'}
>>> temp
{'logs': [{'no': 'val'}]}
```

And this one to add values :

```
>>> temp['logs'][0].update({'yes':'val'})
>>> temp
{'logs': [{'key': 'val', 'yes': 'val'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be unique "key" every time you append it. (If it is for json)

Also making "=" will update your old dictionary

What I have done when I was stuck once is

```
user = {}
name,password,id1 = [],[],[]
user1=session.query(User).all()
for i in user1:
    name=i.name
    password=i.password
    id1=i.id
    user.update({ id1:{
            "name" : name,
            "password" : password,
          }
        })
```

check this link might be helpful to you

[How to convert List of JSON frames to JSON frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345004/how-to-convert-list-of-json-frames-to-json-frame)

Answer (score 0):

Note that adding a dictionary (or any object) to a list only stores a reference, not a copy.

You can therefor do this:

```
>>> temp = {'logs': []}
>>> log_entry = {'key1': 'val1'}
>>> temp['logs'].append(log_entry)
>>> temp
{'logs': [{'key1': 'val1'}]}
>>> log_entry['key2'] = 'val2'
>>> temp
{'logs': [{'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1'}]}
```

However, you might be able to circumvent to whole issue by using dict comprehension (only in Python >=2.7)

```
>>> temp = {'logs': [{key: value for key, value in my_generator}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

`temp = {
   'logs':[]
}`

`[temp['logs'].append(log) for log in errors['logs']]`

Your log data would be list with multiple dictionary